# Is there a word that describes someone with a light footprint?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, compound-adjectives

I need a word to describe someone who lives a happy, purposeful life without needing a lot of resources. The words "light footprint" and "low maintenance" come to mind, but I'd like a word/adjectival phrase that doesn't sound so modern.

Comment: Do you mean physically light-footed, or little environmental detriment?

Comment: Please read the description on the single-word-request tag, and improve your question. It lacks a sample sentence, although it shows some research/effort.

Comment: The duplicate nature hinges on the example ' "Mr.K is not a wasteful man. He leads a very {_mundane_} life." ' and '... In the example ... I am referring mundane to be "ordinary" and in positive sense.' / An example sentence here _might_ make the question legitimate on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

The question is **I need a word (adjective) to describe someone who lives a happy, purposeful life without needing a lot of resources**

Before the days of buzz words and trendy phrases we would have just said

**they lived a simple life**. or **had a simple life style**

In fact this was a very clever use of the word simple [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simple?topic=plain-and-ordinary) as simple can be used as an adjective to describe multiple things: easy, plain and natural,  being among them, all of which would be relative in this case.

> He was just a simple fisherman.

Note Jesus was described as just a **simple** fisherman to portray exactly this meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As in:

She has a gentle, **unassuming** manner.  [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unassuming)

**unassuming**
adj.

> Exhibiting no pretensions, boastfulness, or ostentation; modest.